# How to put image behind embedded youtube iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, position

i'd like to put an image behind my youtube iframe. The image will act as a visual frame around the youtube window. I've tried different methods, but either both elements where placed after each other, or the iframe was positioned relative to the window size of the browser. Both elements will sit in a table.    I want the youtube window to sit about in the center of the background image and nothing should put both elements apart (like changing the window size of the browser etc.) In addition it would be pretty nice to have a custom preview picture for the video instead of the youtube window until it gets clicked (and possible put the custom picture back in place when the youtube video has been watched).

Answer (score 5):

Set `background-image` behind your Youtube `iframe` and use JavaScript for custom preview picture.

### TRY - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bon5hj31/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="background-video">
    <div onclick="play();" id="vidwrap"></div>
</div>

<!-- <iframe width="480" height="360" src="[YouTube Video URL]?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"> -->

<script type="text/javascript">function play(){document.getElementById('vidwrap').innerHTML = '<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7-7knsP2n5w?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';}</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background-video {

    /* Your background image */

    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/580x460');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 50px;
}

#vidwrap {

    /* Your thumbnail image */

    background: url('http://www.edu.uwo.ca/img/click_to_play.png') no-repeat center;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:480px;
    height:360px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to implement this in react.js?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to have your youtube-iframe in a  container and set the image as background-image of this container? Like this:

```
<div class="youtube">
 <-- youtube iframe or target here -->
</div>
```

and css:

```
div.youtube {
 background: url('url-of-your-image.png')
 padding: 50px; // adjust as needed
}
```